# descargas simultáneas con php, extrayendo información de mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

verán tengo un código en php que hace consultas a una base de datos, donde hay un ID que representa a una persona y otro registro de un adeudo y al finalizar me genera la descarga de un documento en word con su respectiva información, probé para ver que todo funcionara para 1 registro y pues lo hace bien, el problema viene cuando generalizo y lo hago para todos los registros de mi base de datos,es decir, para todas las personas que tengo registradas  pero sólo me descarga un archivo, el de la 1ra persona que encuentra en la base de datos y para las demás personas ya no lo hace, utilizo el "while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))" para ir extrayendo la información y dentro de este while es donde hago la descarga.

Utilizo phpword para generar el documento y hacer la descarga.

### -----------------------------------------------------------

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/PHPWord-master/src/PhpWord/Autoloader.php';
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader::register();
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor;

//conexion con la Bd llamada "datosgenrales" y "adeudos"


$queryID="SELECT numCuenta FROM  `datosgenerales` "; 

$cantidadID = mysql_query($queryID, $con);


while ($IDperson = mysql_fetch_array($cantidadID)) {        

    $IDperson = mysql_fetch_array($cantidadID);     
    $IDpersona= $IDperson['numCuenta'];     

    $queryCuenta = "SELECT count(*) from adeudos where cuentas='".$IDpersona."'";

    $queryAdeudos = "SELECT  adeudos.total as dineroTotal, adeudos.concepto as tipoAdeudo
    FROM adeudos, datosgenerales
    WHERE adeudos.cuentas =  '".$IDpersona."' 
    AND datosgenerales.numCuenta ='".$IDpersona."'";


    $nombre = $IDpersona; //variable para ponerla en el documento word

    $resulCuenta = mysql_query($queryCuenta, $con);
    $cuent=intval($cuentaRep[0]);


        $templateWord = new TemplateProcessor('plantilla1.docx'); //plantilla word
        // --- Asignamos valores a la plantilla
        $templateWord->setValue('nombre',$nombre); //imprime en plantilla word


        // --- Guardamos el documento
        $templateWord->saveAs('notificacion'.$aux.'.docx');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=notificacion".$aux.".docx; charset=iso-8859-1");
        echo file_get_contents('notificacion'.$aux.'.docx');

}

?>
```

Comment: Coloca el código que tienes hasta ahora para entender mejor tu problema.

Comment: Si podrías poner el código php que utilizas creo que nos simplifcarías para poder ayudarte, quizás estás concatenando mal las variables.

Comment: listo @Federico

Comment: listo @JuanPinzón

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es posible porque el protocolo http está pensado en bajar un archivo a la vez.
Una posible solución es meter todos los archivos en un zip
Eso lo puedes hacer dentro del while y cuando terminas mandas el zip recién generado
http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

Comment: mmmmm pero aún así, necesitaría descargar todos los archivos dentro del while almacenarlos en una carpeta y después generar e zip al terminar el programa, se necesitaría descargar cada archivo ¿no?

Comment: revisa el enlace que puse, puedes crear el zip desde php  http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php

Comment: gracias @Juan Manuel Doren tenías razón dentro del código puse que me fuera generando el archivo y al final lo guarda en un zip :D y me ayudó mucho tu idea y esta página http://blog.unijimpe.net/crear-archivos-zip-con-php/

Comment: que bueno, dale un voto a la respuesta :)

Comment: oye alguna otra idea para que en mi zip  se almacenen miles de archivos ya que sólo se guardan 99 archivos y yo quiero guardar más de 10,000

Comment: sube el código que estás usando, no veo que exista una restricción en el número ¿te da alg{un mensaje de error?

Comment: pues no me genera ningún error, hasta hora, pero pues la verdad necesito generar 48,000 archivos dentro del zip y se queda en 23,890

Comment: mmh! puede que sea un problema de memoria de tu servidor, igual 23.000 es un número grande :)  o puede ser que se caiga por timeout...